# How to use count and insert in sql?

Tags: sql, insert, count

I have a table which has two rows id and name, i want to use Count function in insert such that I can use query as:

```
Insert into table1(ID,Name) Values (Count + 1,'Name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then,

```
var CurrentCount = Count + 1;
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, Name) VALUES (CurrentCount, Name);
```

Why not use the default Sql functions, IsIdentity property. Which would automatically increment the value for you. And you won't even have to run this function to increment the value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all database management systems have built in some magic for this. MySQL's using AUTO_INCREMENT, Postgres sequences, MS SQL Server identity columns, ...

It depends of your database.

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2012

Comment: @user3475467: you can use the statement provided by Min and lookup the documentation provided by Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: removed the column from the statement.  Now try it.

If you are using Transact SQL you can change the ID property to auto-increment.  use this:

```
    alter table1 alter [ID] int identity(1,1) not null
```

After that, it will add 1 to any inserted row

Comment: @user3475467  which error get you from your MS SQL server ?